# ¿Cómo pasar esta consulta de SQL a Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT YEAR (created_at) 
FROM students;
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT YEAR (created_at) FROM students.   No puedo obtener los años de la columna created_at. Solo eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `DB`(para poder hacer uso del query builder Fluent) al incio de tu controlador y posteriormente haz la consulta así

Al inicio de tu controlador debes hacer lo siguiente

```
use DB;
```

Posteriormente dentro de la class Controller y del método que tengas definido para esta acción de consulta, haz lo siguiente

```
$data = DB::table('registros')
            ->selectRaw("DISTINCT YEAR(created_at) AS Distintos")
            ->get();
        return $data;
```

1. Como puedes ver hago uso de `selectRaw()` para ejecutar funciones de sql que no vienen por defecto en el ORM, este método se puede usar en lugar de `DB::raw()`
2. el nombre de la columna que deseas recuperar debe ser pasado así sin comillas y opcionalmente asignarle un alias
3. El método estático `table()` recibe como parámetro el nombre de la tabla de tu base de datos a la cual deseas aplicarle la consulta

**RESULTADO OBTENIDO(es solo un ejemplo)**

```
[
  {
   "Distintos": 2013
  },
  {
   "Distintos": 2015
  }
]
```

Comment: Solucionado!!. Muchas gracias Alfredo Paz! Ya lo tengo.

Answer (score 0):

si usas  [Carbon](https://styde.net/componente-carbon-fechas-laravel-5/)

Puedes obtenerla así:

```
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $date = $date->format('Y');
```

Ahora si quieres obtenerla desde la base de datos con tu sql sería el mismo que estas ocupando:

```
create table students (
    name varchar(10),
    created_at date
);

INSERT INTO students (name, created_at) values ("my name", NOW());
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR (created_at) FROM students;
```

La anterior consulta devuelve 2018.

Además de la funcion YEAR():

```
SELECT YEAR('2017/08/25') AS Year;
```